# How to get the Cursor Style of window in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, extjs

I am automating a web application built on EXT JS. Whenever I click on some control cursor changes style. I want to get the hold of the cursor style and pause my script.

Comment: please let us know what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to get the cursor style using java script snippet. for eg "document.body.style.cursor" but it is always returning blank value. I tried to the same thing for panel as well but doesn't seem to work,

Answer (score -1):

The cursor is changed through normal CSS. It is not possible to pause the script on CSS change.

If you need the cursor style because you want to snoop "how they did it", you can use Chrome Web Developer tools.

You have to right-click the component where you want to see the cursor, and select "Inspect". Then you have to go to the "Computed" styles tab and resize it so that the first dozen or so lines are visible (or filter down to "cursor", which is the CSS property used). And then you can hover the component and you will see that the "cursor" property changes.

[image]

After a short while, you may become tired of trying around and put [a list of available cursors, like this one on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), into your bookmarks.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am using Selenium Automation Script which will pause the script for me. Pause condition needs to be dependent on the cursor style. In my current application this cursor style changes to busy state irrespective of the element whenever some user interaction is made. I tried to check the css style of body but it remains unchanged. Do you have any other suggestion for me ?